# how to extract the key and value of text file in java?

Tags: java, regex

I am not able find the way to extract those data like below in java. I have also used regex for separating the data which comes in the same line but I am unable to tackle this problem, this is for practice only.

example text files:-

```
school     highschool       name      delhischool
address    delhi            street     metros-station 
school     SecondarySchool   name      metroSchool
address    mombie            street     bus-station
```

**eg: school:highschool
name:delhischool
similary other**

example code:-

```
    File myObj = new File("C:\\Users\\text1.txt");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data;
//                while (myReader.nextLine().contains("----"))
                data = myReader.nextLine();
                if (data.contains("name")) {
                    List<String> split = Arrays.asList(data.split("\\s{3}+"));
//                    String[] split = data.split("\\s{3,1000}+");
                    System.out.println(split);
//                    System.out.println(data);
```

Comment: Okay...now  that's confusing. Which is the file format? Colon (:) delimited or space delimited? Your first example shows two lines of space delimited data...is the first line a Header line?

Comment: @DevilsHnd sorry thats my mistake i give you google drive link :- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hJgvRZ7thl5nn0SGH-PWj7ndgEvxVOcc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The best approach in my opinion would be to create a class to support the file data you want to read in. Here is an example class for this named **SchoolData**:

```
public class SchoolData {

    private String school;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String street;

    // Constructor 1
    public SchoolData() {    }

    // Constructor 2
    public SchoolData(String school, String name, String address, String street) {
        this.school = school;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getSchool() {
        return school;
    }

    public void setSchool(String school) {
        this.school = school;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder(this.school).append(", ").append(this.name).append(", ")
                .append(this.address).append(", ").append(this.street).toString();
    }

}
```

To read the data file you might try something like this (there are many ways to accomplish this):

```
File myObj = new File("SchoolData.txt");
List<SchoolData> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
// 'Try With Resources' used here to auto-close reader.
try (Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj)) {
    String data;
    while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
        data = myReader.nextLine().trim();  // Get fist line of record data
        // If the line isn't blank and it starts with the word 'school' then
        // it must be the start of a new data record.
        if (!data.isEmpty() && data.toLowerCase().startsWith("school")) {
            String[] lineParts = data.split("\\s+");
            String school = lineParts[0] + ":" + lineParts[1];
            String name = lineParts[2] + ":" + lineParts[3];
            data = myReader.nextLine().trim(); // Get second line of record data
            lineParts = data.split("\\s+");
            String address = lineParts[0] + ":" + lineParts[1];
            String street = lineParts[2] + ":" + lineParts[3];
            // Create a new instance of SchoolData which will be held 
            // within the dataList List Interface to access as you like.
            dataList.add(new SchoolData(school, name, address, street));
        }
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}

System.out.println("Display all instances of SchoolData:");
System.out.println();
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(dataList.get(i).getSchool());
    System.out.println(dataList.get(i).getName());
    System.out.println(dataList.get(i).getAddress());
    System.out.println(dataList.get(i).getStreet());
    System.out.println("===============================");
    System.out.println();
}

System.out.println("Another way to display all instances of SchoolData");
System.out.println("using the SchoolData#toString() method:"); 
System.out.println();
for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(dataList.get(i).toString());
}
```

If all goes well and with the file data you provided, your console window should display something like this:

```
Display all instances of SchoolData:

school:highschool
name:delhischool
address:delhi
street:metros-station
===============================

school:SecondarySchool
name:metroSchool
address:mombie
street:bus-station
===============================

Another way to display all instances of SchoolData
using the SchoolData#toString() method:

school:highschool, name:delhischool, address:delhi, street:metros-station
school:SecondarySchool, name:metroSchool, address:mombie, street:bus-station
```

Comment: thanks alot for our support and  my mistake was checking contain type of the data and  by your help  i can do any kind of task another question is that  if the